# Installing Open Sans font on my mac screws up Dropbox website

Tags: mac, fonts, web

Dropbox website uses open sans font. I installed the font on my mac so I could use it in my projects. Now dropbox website looks so bad because it is reading the local font instead of the webfont that is specified.

How can I keep the font local but have chrome not read it?